# Can we get the option to sort favourites into categories?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

My favourites *list* is getting large, well not that large - only 57.

It's large enough for me that I often don't bother looking through it to find one of my favourites. I mostly use the site search or find (ctrl+f) to get what I am looking for.

It would be nice to be able to sort my favourites into categories. Like where I can assign labels/folders like "How-To's", "Projections", "Data Sources", "Topology", "General Reference" etc...

I am currently in the process of subscribing to all my favourites with the RSS feed and organizing them in my rss reader based on my own labels/folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It became available in 04<sup>th</sup>, January, 2013 [a new elasticsearch-based search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) which included the term `infavorites:` as an addtional option for searching favorite threads.

The below answer of John Seigel brings all details:

[Search in favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)

For instance, use:

```
 infavorites:mine is:question [qgis]
```

to search all questions self marked as favorite and which are labeled with [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis)

One can search for all users together favorited threads in a specific topic:

```
infavorites:all is:question [qgis]
```

and also another users' favorited threads (e.g. all threads favorited by you and which are labeled with [projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection)) :

```
infavorites:1297 is:question [projection]
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. It would still be nice to sort by my own categories (not rely on crowd sourced labels).

Comment: Yes, I understand your point of view. Maybe now one knows about this feature he/she can review some poorly tagged threads inside their favorite lists and make them more searchable.